# How to output effective maven dependencies?

Tags: maven

I have a large project with numerous dependencies.
An I want to list all dependencies in console. Like with `mvn dependency:tree`, but i need to list effective list of dependencies.

How can i achieve this?

PS. Effective list of dependencies means the actual dependencies used when the project got compiled by command `mvn compile` dependency:tree can list dependency of different versions. I want to know the definite version, which will be resolved when compiled

Comment: What do you mean by "effective list of dependencies"? What's missing by `:tree` ?

Comment: Can you post some examples here where something is not clear...

Comment: @khmarbaise oh god, I already thoroughly wrote the issue. How can it still be unclear!
When you launch JetBrains IDEA, you r able to execute Mvn->show effective pom.
I want the same in console.

Comment: As you wrote `Mvn->show effective pom.` in your comment which is something completely different than: `effective list of dependencies`...  Hm.. interesting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `mvn dependency:list` gives the list of dependencies as it is resolved by Maven.

To print the effective POM, use `mvn help:effective-pom`